# how to update gridview when changing date in CalendarExtender without having a button?

Tags: gridview, calendarextender

Is it possible to update a gridview when you change a date in a textbox, using CalendarExtender, without having a button ??  I'm not shure what I can use.
I use C# in VisualStudio 2008, 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hooking up the TextBox's TextChanged event? Perhaps that would help, since the TextBox's contents change when one selects a new date in the extender.